# Screenshots not being auto generated with Ruby-Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, screenshot

I am using Ruby Rspec to test a webapp that doesn't use rails, thus I don't have a rails_helper.rb, just a spec_helper.rb. I can manually trigger a screenshot but I can't figure out how to trigger the screenshots on a failure.

**spec_helper.rb:**

```
# frozen-string-literal: true
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara-screenshot/rspec'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'site_prism'

Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/page_objects/*/*.rb'].each do |page_object|
  require page_object
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
 Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.save_path = "#{Dir.pwd}/screenshots"

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.app_host = "REDACTED"
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 20
```

**my_spec.rb**

```
describe 'spec' do
    before(:each) do
      @my_page = login_and_open_my_page
    end
    it "fails" do
       expect(5).to eq(6)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do that in an RSpec after block.  You can define that in your RSpec configuration, etc and should basically boil down to

```
after(:each) do |example|
  if example.exception
     # Do whatever you want to happen on failure
     Capybara.current_session.save_and_open_screenshot
  end 
end
```

You'd need that block to run before you reset the session, so it needs to be defined after whatever block you have defined for doing the reset.